# how to calculate the output value of an lm335 sensor

Tags: lm335

i am having a problem in calculating the output value from the [lm335](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm335.pdf) precision temperature sensor where its output value is the input of ADC0804.
With increase in temperature the value decreases instead of increasing.What might be the problem?

Comment: Please add a schematic of how you have the LM335 connected.

Answer (score 2):

Without a schematic, it is difficult to surmise what might be the problem.

At a guess, the device is not connected as shown in Figure 4 or 5 of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm335.pdf), fed from the circuit's V<sub>cc</sub> through a an appropriate resistor (R1 in those figures), as described in the datasheet.

R1 is calculated such that current through the device is 1 mA (or up to 5 mA) with a voltage drop across the device for your ambient temperature, much like the calculation of current limiting resistors for LEDs.

The voltage drop calculation is provided on Page 8 of the datasheet.